# How come the kernel on up-to-date Ubuntu-14.04.2_LTS servers are not the same? 3.13 or 3.16

Tags: 14.04, kernel, lts

I have multiple servers running Ubuntu-14.04.2_LTS, just occurred to me that some are running the 3.13 kernel while others runs 3.16; all are maintained identically, so what would explain this?

Comment: Check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack , also did you recently fresh install 14.04.2 in any of your servers?

Comment: run the command  `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`  on each machine and see if there are any difference there. It looks like you may have the "utopic" lts kernel (3.16) installed on some machines and not on others.

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure the servers using the 3.16 kernel are 14.04LTS and not 14.10? I believe running the following command on each server will verify this: `uname -a`

Comment: or  `dpkg -l | grep linux-generic`

Comment: @mchid all servers run LTS to minimize impact/uptime on production environment; I've figured it out, see the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by @xangua, stumble upon this :

> Trusty
>
> The 14.04.2 and newer point release will ship with an updated kernel and  X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can use > the following to install the newer kernel from 14.10 (Utopic):
>
> DESKTOP...
>
> SERVER
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic
> ```

Also, as @mchid pointed out, servers running 3.16 had the package installed :

```
nul@nebula:~$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic       3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic       3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic 3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic      3.16.0.36.28                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Tried it on a BETA server (14.04.2_LTS running 3.13) and it worked like a charm; as stated, some servers must have been installed with a recent ISO, others must have been dist-upgraded from earlier versions.